# How to combine Mongo DB variables with wildcard characters

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to parametrise a number of queries with a variable. So select all documents with a specific substring in field `key`

The following is working code:

```
db.getCollection('df_FI').find({
  $and: 
    [
      {key:{"$in":[/2021-08-01_2021-08-11_Reported/]}}
    ]
})
```

This needs to be applied to many queries so I'd like a variable / constant to replace the string. The following is failing. How to combine a variable with wildcard characters?

```
key_sub_string = "2021-08-01_2021-08-11_Reported";
db.getCollection('df_FI').find({
  $and: 
    [
      {key:{"$in":["/" + key_sub_string + "/"]}}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Are you performing MongoDB queries in CLI or are you doing some backend queries?

Comment: Running in NoSQLBooster

Comment: Just tried it with deleteMany. I get  "$regex is not defined", Di I need to add a declaration?

Comment: Try to put $regex in the "", like "$regex"

Comment: Seems not to work. I'll try .remove and a let assignment

Comment: I am not familiar with NoSQLBooster, but that is the syntax that you would use for MongoDB query.

Comment: Worked! Tks
key_sub_string = "2020-06-01_2020-06-10_Reported"
db.df_FI.remove({"key" :  { $regex : key_sub_string}})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `$and`, since you only have one expression. You can use `$regex` to check if some `key` has a substring:

```
db.collection.find({key : {$regex : substring}});
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fBlO04PdVXH